# The question about use Vss ,vs 2005,vs2010 at the same time

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I want use vs 2005 ,2010 and visual source safe at the same time ,but .sln file is incompatible。
Every time i opened my projcet will pop-up converted file tooltip in vs 2010,when i turn into another version vs will pop-up cannt open file tips.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you not switch to VS 2010 and get rid of 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host all internal files (code) in the same place, and build a different solution/project file for each Visual Studio.
This is a very bad solution, as you will have to insert files that created in one version into the project's of the other, but if you must work with all of them...

Answer (score 0):

I've also found that various versions of VS will change any resource files as well.   We had that issue between VS2003 and VS2005.

The best thing is to stick with the most common denominator that everyone can use.   Eventually upgrading everyone at the same time.